# Receiving several read receipt from myself

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using Outlook with Microsoft Exchange - an email was sent to several external addresses, and a read receipt was received back several times but for my email! note that I haven't CCed myself. 
What could cause this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: You sent an email out, did not copy yourself, and recipients answered Yes to "Do you want to send the email receipt?" . This is normal Outlook / Exchange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Outlook desktop client? If so, please log in to your webmail and send messages with "Request a read receipt" to see if the issue has any difference.
If they can all work fine on the web mail, there might be something wrong with your Outlook client, please try repairing your Office.